# Python :How to iterate over a list that has numbers as it's contents

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to itereate over an integer list. Unfortunately, I am getting an error in this line.

```
odd_numbers = []
    for i in  range(1, 21, 2):
        odd_numbers.append(i)
    for odd in len(odd_numbers):
        print(odd_numbers[odd])
```

How do I iterate over these integers using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use `range` for the second loop. You cannot iterate in `int` but list of `int`s:

```
odd_numbers = []
for i in  range(1, 21, 2):
    odd_numbers.append(i)
for odd in range(len(odd_numbers)):
    print(odd_numbers[odd])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid the len() in the second for loop. You have to iterate over the list, not over the length of this list (Which is an integer and leads to your error message). The following code runs.

```
odd_numbers = []
for i in  range(1, 21, 2):
    odd_numbers.append(i)
for odd in odd_numbers:
    print(odd)
```